# Type-safe swift NSEntityDescriptor insertNewObjectForEntityForName(_:inManagedObjectContext:)

Tags: swift, generics, core-data

`NSEntityDescriptor`'s `insertNewObjectForEntityForName(_:inManagedObjectContext:)` returns `AnyObject`. If I name my entities the same as their `NSManagedObject` subclasses, is there any way to create a generic extension method on `NSManagedObject` that returns the correct type so consumers don't need to downcast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public extension NSManagedObject {
    public class func entityName() -> String {
        let moduledName = self.description()
        if let firstDotRange = moduledName.rangeOfString(".") {
            return moduledName.substringFromIndex(firstDotRange.endIndex)
        } else {
            return moduledName
        }
    }

    public class func insert(#managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext) -> Self {
        return _insert(managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)
    }

    private class func _insert<SelfType>(#managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext) -> SelfType {
        return NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(entityName(),
            inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as SelfType
    }
}
```

Ideally, we would just write `insert(managedObjectContext:)` like:

```
public class func insert(#managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext) -> Self {
    return NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(entityName(),
        inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as Self
}
```

But this fails with:

```
'Self' is only available in a protocol or as the result of a class method; did you mean 'NSManagedObject'?
            inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as Self
                                                             ^~~~
                                                             NSManagedObject
```

So, we simply leave it as a result of the original `insert(managedObjectContext:)` method and let swift's generic type inference make `SelfType` the appropriate type.